# Select method based on field in class

Tags: java, field, visitor-pattern

So I have a class that contains a String-field:

```
public class A {
    private String type = ...
    public String getType(){
        return this.type;
    }
    public void setType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

I also have a list of all possible types, there are twelve and possibly more in the future.

Now I want to write a method that gets an object of class A and calls a specific method depending on which "type" is in the class.
Is there a smarter solution than writing 12 (or more) if-statements?
Normally I would use the Visitor-pattern but I don't want to create twelve new classes.

edit:
I ended up creating a

```
Map<String,Function<A,String>> map = new HashMap<String,Function<A,String>>
```

and then call

```
A a;
...
map.get(a.getType).apply(a);
```

Comment: What do these methods do? Why not place them in the class of each type? It sounds like you are willing to trade code quality for a few lines of code saved.

Comment: The solution you ended up with is superior (IMHO) that the given answers. However, Andreas' recommendation for an enum over string is probably worth heeding.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of storing type as a "free-form" text value, you should be using an `enum`, since you have a well-defined list of values.

You can even have the different enums implement the same method differently, by using an abstract method. This will allow you to totally eliminate the error-prone `switch` statements.

Below is an example showing both instance values and abstract methods. The pattern shown will keep the implementation out of the enum, while having the compiler catch all uses when a new enum is added.

```
public enum Type {
    INTEGER("Integer") {
        @Override
        public void apply(Action action, A a) {
            action.applyInteger(a);
        }
    },
    STRING ("Text") {
        @Override
        public void apply(Action action, A a) {
            action.applyString(a);
        }
    };

    private String displayName;

    private Type(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return this.displayName;
    }

    public abstract void apply(Action action, A a);

}

public interface Action {

    public void applyInteger(A a);
    public void applyString(A a);

}

public class A {
    private Type type;
    public Type getType(){
        return this.type;
    }
    public void setType(Type type){
        this.type = type;
    }
    public void apply(Action action) {
        this.type.apply(action, this);
    }
}
```

When you add a new type to the TYPE enum, you also add a new method to the Action interface, which will force you to implement that method in all implementations of the interface. With `switch` statements, you'd get no such safety.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JDK 7 or greater  go for a `switch` which accepts String as a parameter and write cases for each.

```
  switch (type) {
         case "SomeX":
             yourInstance.invokeMethod();
             break;
         case "SomeY":
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the other answers are correct but, by reading the question I think the more direct answer will be using introspection and convention:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test {
    public static class A {
        private String type;
        public String getType(){
            return this.type;
        }
        public void setType(String type){
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    public static class Actions {

        public void runForType1(A a) {
            System.out.println("It's type 1");
        }

        public void runForType2(A a) {
            System.out.println("It's type 2");
        }

        public void runForType3(A a) {
            System.out.println("It's type 3");
        }
    }

    public static class Runner {
        Actions actions;
        public Runner(Actions a) {
            this.actions = a;
        }

        public void run(A a) {
            try {
                Method m = actions.getClass().getMethod("runFor" + a.getType(), A.class);
                m.invoke(actions, a);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner r = new Runner(new Actions());

        A type1 = new A();
        type1.setType("Type1");
        A type2 = new A();
        type2.setType("Type2");
        A type3 = new A();
        type3.setType("Type3");

        r.run(type1);
        r.run(type2);
        r.run(type3);
    }
}
```

expected output for the example will be:

```
It's type 1
It's type 2
It's type 3
```

If convention is not possible you can always create a HashMap with a type to method name mapping.